# Range of a random variable - measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space.

Sometimes, the convention is used that a random variable is a map from a probabilty space to $\mathbb{R}$, but let's not adopt this. So let $X$ be a random variable with range $E$,

so $X \colon \Omega \rightarrow E$.

The question now is: Why must $E$ be measurable? What does it mean for a range not to be measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, whatever may $E$ be, you will want to look at the so-called *law* $\mathbf{P}_X$ of $X$, which will have to be a probability on $E$, which will have to be endowed with an $\sigma$algebra. To do this, as you already have a probability $\mathbf{P}$ on $\Omega$, you will want to use it, and define $\mathbf{P}_X$ by setting $\mathbf{P}_X(A) = \mathbf{P}(X^{-1}(A))$ for certain $A$'s subsets of $E$. But for the right hand side to make sense, $X^{-1}(A)$ should be measurable in $\Omega$ for $A$ subset of $E$. You immediately get this by assuming $X$ measurable, and defining $\mathbf{P}_X$ on measurable sets of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$? Then $E$ by itself actually does not need to be a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$ for $X$ to be a valid random variable. For example, consider the coin flip $X$ that is either $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ each.

We can consider $X$ as a function $\Omega \to \mathbb R$. We can also consider $X$ as a function $\Omega \to \{0,1\}$. We can even consider $X$ as a function $\Omega\to E$ where $E$ is some nasty non-measurable set (containing $0$, $1$ and some nasty nonmeasurable set of other real numbers).

The important thing isn't that $E$ is measurable, it's that $X$ is a measurable function. Recall the definition of a measurable function: The *inverse image* of any measurable subset of the range is a measurable subset of $\Omega$ (that is, a member of $\mathcal F$). In the coin flip example, it is measurable, because the inverse image of **any** subset of the range (measurable or not!) is either one of the following 4 options: the empty set, the whole $\Omega$, the "half" of $\Omega$ that goes to zero or the "half" of $\Omega$ that goes to one. (Think why.)

Comment: No, I rather meant that $E$ could be an arbitrary set, for example $\mathbb{R}^d$ or whatever. 

Thank you for your answer, I will think about this a while!

Comment: If $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^d$ or $\mathbb C^d$ then the same reasoning applies. This can be extended to any infinite-dimensional vector space with a topology (for instance Banach spaces are a pretty popular choice to define random variables on). For weirder kinds of spaces, a random element might no longer be "just" a measurable function. For example, choosing a random Borel set from the Effros-Borel space $\mathbf F(X)$ on some topological space $X$, the standard definitions are slightly different and your question no longer applies. This is considered an advanced topic in probability.